# Reception of broadcast in service

Tags: android

Is there a way to get broadcast reception in a Service context?
I have tried adding the `receiver` intent-filter in the manifest file but of course Android tries to instantiate the service every time and an exception is throwed.

How can I do this?

( did I mention I am a complete noob on Android ? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get broadcast reception in a Service context?

Not directly. A `Service` can register a `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically via `registerReceiver()`, or you can have a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` "forward" the event to a `Service` via `startService()`.

Comment: marvelous!  I figure out the missing pieces. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: hi CommonsWare and jldupont , could you please provide the code snippets to add in my service class and the changes in the manifest file? I am not able to work it out. I created new member BroadcastReceiver class in my service class and then registered the broadcast receiver instantiated object with intent filter for CONNECTIVITY_ACTION. Then I updated manifest file with  new receiver  like this " <receiver android:name=".MyService$ConnUpdate">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>".

Answer (score 1):

Android will instantiate a service to handle any specific Intent for which it has registered - or if the service is running it will enqueue the Intent for handling as soon as its current operations are complete.  To watch broadcasts,, register a BroadcastReceiver and forward what is seen to your Service.

If your Service is throwing an exception, something is wrong with it.  Post a complete stack trace for your app's exception, which you can see using adb and logcat as [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat), or in the logcat view in Eclipse.